# Multiple inheritance with R.oo package

Tags: r, multiple-inheritance

I am currently migrating to R and I would like to use an object oriented design. Although I am not sure I fully understand the implications of choosing one of the various implementations (S3, S4, Reference Classes or R.oo package), I have decided to use the R.oo package, mainly because it seems to be aligned well with my rudimentary understanding of OOP, gained from other programming languages.

I also use this occasion to do a complete overhaul of my object structure and I keep coming back to the fact that multiple inheritance would be the most "natural" way to create many of my classes. In R.oo, the inheritance is specified by a call to extend() in the constructor, with the first parameter being the parent class, so I tried to call extend twice in the constructor to see if that would do the trick. It did not. The following code, based on an example in the documentation, reproduces the error :

```
setConstructorS3("SavingsAccount", function(balance=0) {

  if (balance < 0)
    throw("Trying to create an account with a negative balance: ", balance);
  extend(Object(), "SavingsAccount",
         .balance = balance
  )
})


setConstructorS3("SavingsAccount2", function(balance=0) {

  if (balance < 0)
    throw("Trying to create an account with a negative balance: ", balance);
  extend(Object(), "SavingsAccount2",
         .balance2 = balance
  )
})

setConstructorS3("SavingsAccount3", function(balance=0) {

  if (balance < 0)
    throw("Trying to create an account with a negative balance: ", balance);
  extend(SavingsAccount2(balance), "SavingsAccount3"
         )
  extend(SavingsAccount(balance), "SavingsAccount3"
  )
})
```

This a very dumb example, but it reproduces the error. Indeed, when you do :

```
SA = SavingsAccount3(23)
```

you get :

```
> SA$.balance2
NULL
> SA$.balance
[1] 23
```

which seems to mean that the second call to extend() overrides the result of the first one. So, my questions are :
- Is it possible to do it with the R.oo package ? (I know it's possible with S4)
- If yes, what should I change in the code above ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I don't know R.oo package but it looks that this call `extend(SavingsAccount3(balance), "SavingsAccount3")` is called recursivley...

Comment: You are right, it was a mistake on my part and I should have checked it before posting. I edited the question to reflect this.